# Windows Batch - CHOICE is useless after manually setting ERRORLEVEL

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I ran into a problem in a bigger batch file I was making, and narrowed it down to a very particular problem. If I manually set the errorlevel like this: `set errorlevel=5` , then the "choice" command can't set or override my errorlevel. How can I get past this from happening?

I made a batch file to test this out. Here it is:

```
@echo off
set errorlevel=5
choice /c 123
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

And the output, if you were to press 2:

```
[1,2,3]?2
5
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I need to use errorlevel when i call another batch file. it returns a code from 1-4. or 0 if it ran correctly. also i have way too much code to just go back and change it.
Plus PATH is also a system variable. I need to change that in my batch file, and I have no problems with it. Just why would ERRORLEVEL not want to change? That's what's confusing me.

Comment: Ah, that's not what your question says. You should [edit] to say that instead. Your question asks about manually setting ERRORLEVEL, and that's really not what you're asking about here.

Comment: To further clarify, ERRORLEVEL as normally used is a keyword, not an environment variable.  Setting an environment variable of the same name is not the same as setting the actual error level.  Unfortunately, if you *do* set an environment variable of the same name, that takes precedence over the keyword, presumably for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Also note that you can use the legacy `if errorlevel` function even if an environment variable named `ERRORLEVEL` exists.  It's awkward in the general case, but works OK for `choice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cmd /c exit /b 5` instead of `set errorlevel=5`

like this:

```
@echo off
cmd /c exit /b 5
choice /c 123
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

Comment: oh, i never knew about the `/b 5` switch at the end of the `exit` command. That works out even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used to use a simple subroutine to set the errorlevel to any value:

```
@echo off

call :errorlevel=5
echo %errorlevel%
goto :EOF

:errorlevel
exit /B %1
```

Comment: It should be noted for the new users that the `=` sign is not needed and is actually treated as equivalent to a space by the `call` command.

Answer (score 1):

System environment variables can be used by the batch file writer, but that is a really bad idea.
`PATH TEMP WINDIR USERNAME USERPROFILE ERRORLEVEL TIME DATE` are some of variable names you should avoid using.  Type `SET` at a cmd prompt to see the usual ones that are in use, but it doesn't show them all.

Choice is operating normally, and other tools will fail to set an errorlevel too.